# $ var declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How should I declare an object variable in Javascript? By mistake, I thought I was in PHP and it worked.

```
$(res.data).each(function(index, value){
                    $src = value.images.fixed_height;
                    $('<a href="'+value.url+'" target="_blank"><img src="' + $src.url + '" width="' + $src.width +'" height="' + $src.height + '"></a>').load(function(){
                        $(this).appendTo("#results").fadeIn();
                    })
                });
```

Then, when I tried to think in terms of Javascript it didn't work,

```
$(res.data).each(function(index, value){
                    var src = value.images.fixed_height;
                    $('<a href="'+value.url+'" target="_blank"><img src="' + src.url + '" width="' + src.width +'" height="' + src.height + '"></a>').load(function(){
                        $(this).appendTo("#results").fadeIn();
                    })
                });
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why the second one shouldn't work so your observation might be incorrect.

Comment: `var someObject = {};` this way you can declare the object in javascript.

Comment: Your first method is creating a global variable.  Your second method is creating a fresh local variable upon each invocation of the `.each()` callback.  Unless you need this value to persist beyond the duration of the loop, the local variable is much better, particularly for such a generic name as `src`.

Comment: I'm with @FelixKling, I can't see why the second example doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the function of the var keyword in ECMAScript 262 3rd Edition/Javascript 1.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript)

Comment: My problem was in the <a> tag. However, where can I read about $ in variables?

Comment: FYI the $ is usually prepended to variable names to denote a jQuery selection. For example: var $nodes = $('.nodes'). It's just a neat way of distinguishing them from other variables.

Comment: `$` has absolutely no significance in variable names. It's just valid to use as first character in variables names, just like `_`. So whether you use `src` or `_src` or `$src` doesn't make a difference. What matters is if you use `var` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the two is that `$src` in the first snippet is global (or at least outside the local scope of the anonymous function) and `src` in the second example is local to that function.

Since the first thing you do is setting the variable, that shouldn't matter for this piece of code, so the second snippet should work exactly as the first one.

The only explanation for different behaviour I can think of, is when another piece of code actually uses this global `src`, and therefor is affected by your second snippet. But this doesn't sound very likely to me, so my guess would be that your test was wrong and either both snippets work, or neither does.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the <a> tag finally. Where can I read about $ variable declaration? I believe it's used for global as you says, but I couldn't find it in documentation.

Comment: No, `$` is just one of the valid characters in an identifier (variable name). The key is in the `var` keyword. Using that, you declare a new variable. If you omit `var`, you are reusing a variable in the closest scope where it was defined. If it wasn't defined at all, it is added in the global scope, that is, it is made a property of the `window` object.